# Use of DelegateExecute key in registry

Tags: windows-10, registry

I was going through the registry keys and values and I came across this key called 'DelegateExecute" which has values like {99969a8f-28e6-4adt-ab9e-b5b8e90d4733}.

What exactly is the purpose of this key and what do its values signify?

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://superuser.com/q/1412104/337631). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry I didn't know that. I'll make sure this doesn't happen again.